# Find and Replace With Elements of a List

Tags: vba, ms-word

While drafting a contract, I don't want to worry about the numbering of the clauses, since they will often change.
Word autonumbering does not fit my needs. I numerate clauses with a Spanish ordinal and feminine word (PRIMERA, SEGUNDA, TERCERA). Word only has the masculine words (PRIMERO, SEGUNDO, TERCERO).
Finding and Replacing Word's masculine words doesn't seem to work.

I am thinking of naming all clauses with the same placeholder name (< clausula >) and then replace that placeholder sequentially with each of the elements in a custom list (PRIMERA, SEGUNDA, TERCERA).

I am having trouble with the For-To statement.
I need to replace the 99 with the total number of results instead of a fixed number to avoid

> "Subscript out of range"

Any ideas on how to correct this or any other ways to achieve my purpose?

```vb
Sub OrdinalTextoFemenino()

Dim arrNumbers As Variant
Dim i As Long
arrNumbers = Split("PRIMERA.- SEGUNDA.- TERCERA.- CUARTA.- QUINTA.-")

With Selection.Find
    For i = 1 To 99
        .ClearFormatting
        .Text = "xclausula"
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.Text = arrNumbers(i - 1)
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceOne, Forward:=True, _
        Wrap:=wdFindContinue
    Next i
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: So why not use SEQ fields with the '\\* OrdText' (ordinal) switch to set the numbering for each paragraph? That way, you wouldn't need 'xclausula' but, even if you used it, a single Find/Replace with the SEQ fields as the replacement would generate all the required numbering without the need for any loops.

Comment: Thank you! I did not know about the SEQ fields. Funny enough, whereas the ordinals in the standard numbering function show up in Spanish (although masculine), in the SEQ fields they show up in English. The problem is I need three things: ordinal + Spanish + feminine. Standard numbering gives me the first two; SEQ just the first. Any other suggestions are welcomed!

Comment: Update: My bad! The document language was in English. I switched it to Spanish and got the same ordinals I get with the standard feature, although the SEQ is much more useful. The third problem still remains: changing from masculine to feminine. Considering the only thing that changes is the last letter (masculine ends with O; feminine with A), I could use a Find and Replace, but if at any time someone updates the fields it will revert back to masculine. Is there a way to replace that A for an O *and* then turn the field into standard text? Thanks!

Comment: You could either lock the fields so they don't update (Ctrl-F11), or unlink them (Ctrl-Shift-F9) to convert them to plain text. Locking the fields allows you to unlock all or certain ones (Ctrl-Shift-F11) if numbered paragraphs are inserted/deleted at a later stage. Either can be done with VBA.

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested fields to do this, but if you have multiple lists, you will need to be careful when re-sequencing items in a list because the first list item will need to be preceded by a `{ SEQ sequencename \r0 \h }` field.

At its simplest, you can put the following at the beginning of the document or perhaps in a header)

```
{ SET s1 “PRIMERA." }{ SET s2 “SEGUNDA." }{ SET s3 “TERCERA." }{ SET s4 “QUARTA." }{ SET s5 “QUINTA." } and more as needed...
```

Then the first list item in each list needs to look like this:

```
{ SEQ x \r0 \h }{ "s{ SEQ x }" }
```

Subsequent items just need the second part:

```
{ "s{ SEQ x }" }
```

All the {} need to be the special field brace pairs that you can insert using ctrl-F9 on Windows desktop Word.

You can put the necessary field codes into two autotexts/building blocks/autocorrects to make them easier to insert.

SET fields have to be in the document somewhere and can be deleted accidentally. So to name the numbers, you can put them in Custom Document Properties (as long as you don't need hundreds of them), named (say) s1, s2, s3 etc. and use then like this

```
{ SEQ x \r0 \h }{ DOCPROPERTY "s{ SEQ x }" }
```

Subsequent items just need the second part:

```
{ DOCPROPERTY "s{ SEQ x }" }
```

But since you can use VBA, a better scheme IMO is to set up Document Variables in the document, e.g. using VBA like this:

```
Sub SetOrdinalStrings()
With ActiveDocument
  .Variables("s1").Value = "PRIMERA."
  .Variables("s2").Value = "SEGUNDA."
  .Variables("s3").Value = "TERCERA."
  .Variables("s4").Value = "QUARTA."
  .Variables("s5").Value = "QUINTA."
  ' etc.
End With
End Sub
```

You only really have to do that once, e.g. to create a template that has the necessary variables set up, and the resulting document does not need to contain any VBA.

Then you would use

```
{ SEQ x \r0 \h }{ DOCVARIABLE "s{ SEQ x }" }
```

Subsequent items just need the second part:

```
{ DOCVARIABLE "s{ SEQ x }" }
```

There are a a couple of other potentiallyuseful things you can do.

If you need multiple independent lists, you can use a different SEQ sequence name for each list, e.g.

```
{ SEQ x \r0 \h }{ DOCVARIABLE "s{ SEQ x }" }
```

for one list, and for another, use

```
{ SEQ y \r0 \h }{ DOCVARIABLE "s{ SEQ y }" }
```

If you need a tab or a space after every sequence number, you can include it in the SET field, Document property value or Document variable. For example, with Document Variables you could use the following VBA if you needed Tabs:

```
Sub SetOrdinalStrings()
With ActiveDocument
  .Variables("s1").Value = "PRIMERA." & vbTab
  .Variables("s2").Value = "SEGUNDA." & vbTab
  .Variables("s3").Value = "TERCERA." & vbTab
  .Variables("s4").Value = "QUARTA." & vbTab
  .Variables("s5").Value = "QUINTA." & vbTab
  ' etc.
End With
End Sub
```